# failed processing manifest: Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-manifest

I received this error after moving my visual studio solution to my desktop,

Upon realizing I already had a copy of my solution on my desktop it was too late to cancel the move (Windows copy sucks)

I simply clicked skip all and moved the merged solution folder to a separate folder on my desktop after receiving the title error (failed processing manifest).

I made a copy of a backup solution folder I had and placed a copy on my desktop, strangely receiving the same error (I suspect the android manifest is corrupted but I have no idea how to fix this).

Can't find a reasonable solution to this error anywhere else on StackOverflow.

Thank you

Comment: Did the project work fine before moving? Try to empty the **obj** and **bin** folders of both the shared project and each platform project. Then open the VS to test the sample again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!, I'll test it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: No, I'm sorry but I deleted all the bin and obj folders I could find but I'm still recieving the same error.

Comment: I've also tried copying the contents of the AndroidManifest.xml and copying that to a new .xml file with no luck.

Comment: Please post the details about the error log, it'll help to get the cause.

Comment: How can I give you the error log please, any further details you can give me?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  failed processing manifest. Assessment 36116_02.Android

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  attribute android:versionNumber not found. Assessment 36116_02.Android C:\Users\nathan\Desktop\Assessment 36116_02\Assessment 36116_02\Assessment 36116_02.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml 3

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  @(Content) build action is not supported Assessment 36116_02.Android C:\Users\nathan\Desktop\Assessment 36116_02\Assessment 36116_02\Assessment 36116_02.Android\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: hello any ideas to fix this?

Comment: I managed to part way fix the issue by changing my AndroidManifest.xml to an 'AndroidResource; in Build Action. Now I recieve Invalid file path error.

Comment: Some configuration files may be lost when moving, try create a new project and copy the code to the new sample.